# Spring conditional annotations (NOT @Conditional)

Tags: java, spring, annotations

Can you make Spring annotations conditional?
I mean for example having the following method:

```
@CachePut(value = "latestALLFXRatesCache", key = "#definition.key")
public AssetValueSnapshot refreshCacheLatestFXValue(DataSource definition) {
    AssetValueSnapshot assetsnap = getLatestFXValueSnapshot(true,definition);
}
```

Can I make the @Cacheput annotation conditional (preferably with another spring annotation)?
For example:

```
if @Profile("XXX") or @Conditional(XXX)
@Cacheput

else
@Cacheable

public AssetValueSnapshot ...
```

Regardless whether this makes sense and knowing that @Profile and @Conditional are not made for this, can I do what I want with annotations or is there some other way in Spring?

Edit after comments:

I'm talking about a broader scope than just a specific annotation (cacheput in this case). I'm wondering if there is an annotation/other way that makes any annotation conditional; regardless of that annotations own conditional behavior.

Comment: `@CachePut` and `@Cacheable` do have `condition` fields but I never used them.

Comment: Where are you calling this? What about placing the conditional there where you are calling, and have two separate methods with different annotations?

Comment: I didn't know that actually, thanks for that. However I'm talking about a broader scope than just a specific annotation. I'm wondering if there is an annotation/other way that makes any annotation conditional; regardless of that annotations own conditional behavior.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Annotations are nothing more then metadata, on themselves they do nothing. You probably want to have the annotation processors/interceptors/fuinctionality conditional. Also why do you want a different `@CachePut` and `@Cacheable` based on profile. You are changing something dangerous (imho) in different environments, which means how are you going to test that?